# Dynamically increment number when it reaches a dynamic input

Tags: javascript

I want to increment only when index passes the condition. Array length is dynamic. input_number is dynamic.

```
let increment = 0
let input_number = 4

array.forEach((arr, index) => {
  // increment++ when index > 4 && index <= 8
  // increment++ when index > 8 && index <= 12
  // increment++ when index > 12 && index <= 16
  // so on...
})


let increment = 0
let input_number = 3

array.forEach((arr, index) => {
  // increment++ when index > 3 && index <= 6
  // increment++ when index > 6 && index <= 9
  // increment++ when index > 9 && index <= 12
  // so on...
})
```

Edit:

```
if(index > 3 && index <= 6) perform only 1 increment
if(index > 6 && index <= 9) perform only 1 increment
if(index > 9 && index <= 12) perform only 1 increment
```

That is my initial code but i have to reiterate it a hundreds or thousand times inside an array. So I have to find a way to make it dynamic

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Yea it's really impossible to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: Just based on the output of the `increment`  value, it seems that you don't really need to iterate over the array. A proper mathematical expression should suffice. You can make use of the size of the array, `array.length`, subtract it by one, given that `array.length` > 0, and then divide it by the `input_number`.

Comment: @RifatBinReza my problem is my array is dynamic so there is no fixed length. I should add a condition like this: increment++ when index > 3(dynamic, divisible by input_number) && index <= 6(dynamic, divisible by input_number). Meaning my condition is dynamic too.

Comment: @ryeballar seems more like `array.length - input_number` as the increment ranges overlap. Only the zero to 4/3 doesn't increment anything. But it's really unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not explain it well. I have updated my question

Comment: I'm still not sure I get it. Are you looking for `increment = Math.ceil(array.length / input_number) - 1`?

Comment: I’m confused at why you have several `if` statements that all cover a range of number and each execute the same function. Why not just do `index > 3 && index <= 12`. What am I missing about the input_number in relation to the if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you check if the `index` is greater than the `inputNumber` and the `index` [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) the `inputNumber` equals `1`.

Using your second example:

```js
const array = Array(13).fill(0);
let increment = 0;
let inputNumber = 3;
console.log(`Initial Increment Value = ${increment}`);
array.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
    if (index > inputNumber && index % inputNumber == 1) {
        console.log(index, ++increment);
    } else {
        console.log(index, 'No Increment');
    }
});
console.log(`Final Increment Value = ${increment}`);
```

Comment: Sorry if I did not explain my question well but it should not increment on 5 but it should increment on the next divisible which is 8 and 12 and so on.

Comment: Ok I interpreted `when index > 4 && index <= 8` as the indexes `5, 6, 7, 8`

Comment: It should only increment once

Comment: Ok can you check now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand.  Is this what you want?

```
let increment = 0
let input_number = 4
let array = [4,10,8,6,4,11,0,2,12,20,33,7,3,4,7];

 function incrementNumber(arr, num) {
   arr.forEach((el, i) => el % num === 0 && el !== 0 ? increment++ : false)
};
incrementNumber(array, input_number)
console.log(increment)
```